# Why is line 13 a = input() affecting a variable on line 15 b=input(int()? python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to write a function that takes user input in the form of a string and assigns it to variable `a`. Then takes a user input of an integer and assigns it to the variable `b`. The problem is when I run my code in the windows command line and enter a string thinking I'm just assigning the variable `a` as a string I get this error saying that it is looking for an int for variable `b`.

If I set variable `b` to equal `input("Please enter starting account balance: ")` instead of `input(int("Please enter starting account balance: "))` the error goes away as expected but without requiring an int I don't know how I can add a try and except statement.

```
def player_setup():
    a = input("Please enter player name: ")
    print(f"Name saved as {a}.")
    b = input(int("Please enter starting account balance: "))
    return Player(name = a, account = b)

from BlackJackPackage.game_support_functions import welcome
from BlackJackPackage.game_support_functions import player_setup


welcome()

while True:
    #Enter Player Name, and Enter Player Starting Money
    human_player = player_setup()
    print(f"Welcome {human_player.name}!")
    print(f"You have ${human_player.account} in your account!.")
    break
```

I'm hoping for variable a to be a string and b to be an integer. These variables should eventually be used to initialize a class called `Player` that needs a `name(string)` and an `account(integer)` input. It looks like the input line for `a` is trying to assign it's input to both `a` and `b` causing a ValueError.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Udemy Python>python Blackjackgame.py
Welcome to Blackjack Basic. First you will need to enter your name and
how much money you have.
Please enter player name: David
Name saved as David.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Blackjackgame.py", line 9, in <module>
    human_player = player_setup()
  File "C:\Users\David Fitzmaurice\Desktop\Udemy         
Python\BlackJackPackage\game_support_functions.py", line 15, in 
player_setup
    b = input(int("Please enter starting account balance: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Please enter starting 
account balance:
```

Comment: b = int(input("Please enter starting account balance: "))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you swapped `int` and `input` keywords, so you are trying to convert the string `"Please enter starting account balance: "` to an integer, which leads to the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Please enter starting 
account balance:`

So instead of

```
b = input(int("Please enter starting account balance: "))
```

It will be as below, where you take the input and then convert it to an integer.

```
b = int(input("Please enter starting account balance: "))
```

Hence the updated code will be

```
def player_setup():
    a = input("Please enter player name: ")
    print(f"Name saved as {a}.")

    #Fixed this line by swapping int and input
    b = int(input("Please enter starting account balance: "))
    return Player(name = a, account = b)

from BlackJackPackage.game_support_functions import welcome
from BlackJackPackage.game_support_functions import player_setup


welcome()

while True:
    #Enter Player Name, and Enter Player Starting Money
    human_player = player_setup()
    print(f"Welcome {human_player.name}!")
    print(f"You have ${human_player.account} in your account!.")
    break
```